# Can I define a style that includes a style in Android?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-styles

I created the following style:

```
<style name="wrap_content">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

I want to create a second style that uses this style. I know I can do the following:

```
<style name="cycle_radio_button" parent="wrap_content">
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">1dp</item>
</style>
```

But is there a way to do instead something like the following:

```
<style name="cycle_radio_button">
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">1dp</item>
    <item name="style">@style/wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

If I could, creating a style based on multiple other styles I have defined would be easier and clearer, rather than having to create a chain of inherited styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inherit from multiple xml styles in Android. The closest thing to that is to inherit a style for a particular type of view. For instance:

```
<style name="style1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:mapViewStyle">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Now, any list views or map views which inherit from "style1" will inherit the styling in "wrap_content".

Attributes like `name="android:listViewStyle"` only apply to specific view types, so this is not going to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Benstrom.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If that has answered your question, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.